# open custom Site Actions link in a new window (SharePoint)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, moss

When using custom actions in SharePoint (for the Site Actions menu) how can I make it so that the links will open up in a new window?

I have tried an approach using jQuery that would attach a hover event via .live() to replace the window.location with a window.open call -- however this proved to be troublesome as it refused to work in IE6 (which a large portion of our users are still using...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is not possible out of box. But it can be done using little hack. Refer to these links

[MSDN Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/a99bf205-e1f5-4653-a83e-cb3ca7861039)

[Blog Post](http://sharepoint.coultress.com/2008/06/sharepoint-2007-custom-action-that.html)